# Swig Python - python scripts stops when PyErr_SetNone(PyExc_StopIteration) is raised

Tags: python, c++, swig

I coded a small container in C++, custom_vector. I want it to be iterable. Here is my swig interface file:

```
%template(vectorModelDescriptor) com_cae::physiology::vector<::IModelDescriptor*>;

%extend com_cae::physiology::vector<::IModelDescriptor*> {
    IModelDescriptor* __getitem__(unsigned int i) {
        if (i >= self->size()) {
            PyErr_SetNone(PyExc_StopIteration);
            return NULL;
        }
        return (*self)[i];
     }
}
```

The function generated by swig is:

```
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return _physiology.vectorAction___getitem__(self, i)
```

When iterating over the container, python code terminates with:  returned a result with an error set. The error is the PyExc_StopIteration. So basicly it will iterate over all the items, go one past, the exception gets raised and the scripts stops.

What is the correct implementation of **getitem**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Writting python code directly works. (at() returns a *&, which borks swig/python, why there's a getitem function.)

```
%extend com_cae::physiology::vector<com_cae::physiology::IModelDescriptor*> {
    IModelDescriptor* getitem(unsigned int i) {  
      return self->at(i);
    }
    size_t __len__() {
       return self->size();
    }
    %pythoncode %{
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if (i >= self.size()):
          raise StopIteration
        return self.getitem(i)
    %}
}
```